# How to maintain the selectedTextRange in a UITextView UIViewRepresentable, it should remain selected even after the focus shifts to another TextField

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit, uitextview

I created this SwiftUI GrowingTextViewRepresentable, which represents a UITextView. I want to maintain the selectedTextRange even after the focus shifts to another TextField/TextView. To achieve this, I tried preserving it with a Binding. I save it in textViewDidEndEditing, expecting it to remain selected when the focus changes to another text field. I then set it again in updateUIView when the view loads. However, it's not working as expected. What am I doing wrong, or how can I achieve this?

FYI:
[GrowingTextView](https://github.com/KennethTsang/GrowingTextView) is just a UITextView subclass, which increases the height when multiline text changes.

**GrowingTextViewRepresentable Code:**

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI
import GrowingTextView


struct GrowingTextViewRepresentable: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    
    let textView = GrowingTextView()
    var placeHolder: String = ""
    var customFont: UIFont = .systemFont(ofSize: 12)
    var placeHolderColor: UIColor = .grey
    var textColor: UIColor = .black
    
    @Binding var text: String
    @Binding var height: CGFloat
    @Binding var selectedText: String
    @Binding var selectedTextRange: UITextRange?
    
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> GrowingTextView {
        textView.delegate = context.coordinator
        textView.font = customFont
        textView.placeholder = placeHolder
        textView.placeholderColor = placeHolderColor
        textView.textColor = textColor
        textView.backgroundColor = .clear
        textView.clipsToBounds = true
        return textView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: GrowingTextView, context: Context) {
        uiView.text = text
        
        if selectedTextRange != nil && uiView.selectedTextRange != selectedTextRange  {
            uiView.selectedTextRange = selectedTextRange
        }
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(text: $text, placeHolder: placeHolder, height: $height, selectedText: $selectedText, selectedTextRange: $selectedTextRange)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, GrowingTextViewDelegate {
        
        @Binding var text: String
        var placeHolder: String
        @Binding var height: CGFloat
        @Binding var selectedText: String
        @Binding var selectedTextRange: UITextRange?
        
        private var tempSelectedBodyTextRange: UITextRange? = nil
        
        init(text: Binding<String>, placeHolder: String, height: Binding<CGFloat>, selectedText: Binding<String>, selectedTextRange: Binding<UITextRange?>) {
            self._text = text
            self.placeHolder = placeHolder
            self._height = height
            self._selectedText = selectedText
            self._selectedTextRange = selectedTextRange
        }
        
        func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
            // UIKit -> SwiftUI
            _text.wrappedValue = textView.text
        }
        
        func textViewDidChangeSelection(_ textView: UITextView) {
            // Fires off every time the user changes the selection.
            if let selectedText = textView.selectedText, let range = textView.selectedTextRange {
                DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                    guard let self = self else { return }
                    self._selectedText.wrappedValue = selectedText
                    self._selectedTextRange.wrappedValue = range
                    self.tempSelectedBodyTextRange = range
                }
                //print(selectedText)
            }
        }
        
        func textViewDidChangeHeight(_ textView: GrowingTextView, height: CGFloat) {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.height = height
            }
        }
        
        func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
            
            // Save the selected range when the text view ends editing
            if let range = tempSelectedBodyTextRange {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self._selectedTextRange.wrappedValue = range
                    textView.selectedTextRange = range
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

extension UITextView {
    var selectedText: String? {
        guard let selectedRange = selectedTextRange else { return nil }
        return text(in: selectedRange)
    }
}
```

**How I'm using it:**

```
import UIKit

struct MyView: View {
    
    @State private var body:String = ""
    @State private var selectedBodyText: String = ""
    @State private var selectedBodyTextRange: UITextRange? = nil
    @State private var heightOfBody: CGFloat = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        
        
        GrowingTextViewRepresentable(placeHolder: "write about...",
                                     text: body, height: $heightOfBody, selectedText: selectedBodyText, selectedTextRange: selectedBodyTextRange)
        .frame(height: heightOfBody)
        .frame(minHeight: 20)
        .onChange(of: viewModel.selectedBodyText, perform: { newValue in
            print("selectedBodyText: \(newValue)")
        })
    }
}
```

I attempted to retain the value in tempSelectedBodyTextRange and then reset it in textViewDidEndEditing, but it didn't work as expected.

Comment: What is the TextSelectedView struct for?

Comment: @ElTomato, it was just for the PreviewProvider, nothing else. But thanks for bringing it to my attention. I'm removing it from the question so that other people don't get confused.

Comment: Just use an `ObservableObject` class to keep track of changes in the text field in question?

Comment: Already implemented it in a live project where the viewModel is an ObservableObject, but unfortunately, it's still not functioning as expected.

Answer (score 0):

`makeUIView` needs to init and return your `GrowingTextView` otherwise it will be lost, e.g.

```
func makeUIView(context: Context) -> GrowingTextView {
    let view = GrowingTextView()
    // or return context.coordinator.view where view is a lazy var
```

`Coordinator` cannot be init with any params or the params will be lost, it must be given the latest params in `updateUIView`, e.g.

```
func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
    Coordinator()
}

func updateUIView(_ uiView: GrowingTextView, context: Context) {
   // update coordinator with any values/bindings that are different
   // update uiView with any values that are different
```

Comment: thanks, @malhai, The issue persists even after trying the solution. 

It seems to be unrelated to preserving the range and more connected to the operating system not allowing the retention of the selected range in the previous textView when a new textField or textView comes into focus.